# how to do a like query using mgo package for golang

Tags: mongodb, go, sql-like, mgo

I am trying to do a `like` query using mgo with no luck.

what I want is a mongodb query similar to

```
db.organisation.find( { "permalink" : /org.*/ } )
```

I am still stuck at

```
sess.DB(db).C(cApp).
    Find(bson.M{"permalink": "org:bms.*"}).
    All(&m)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [bson.Regex](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#RegEx) to specify a regular expression value using the unmaintained MGO client package.

```
sess
  .DB(db)
  .C(cApp)
  .Find(bson.M{"permalink": bson.RegEx{"org.*", ""}})
  .All(&m)
```

Comment: It dosen't work. Right answer is `bson.M{"permalink": bson.M{"$regex": "org.*", "$options": ""}}`, https://calmops.com/db/mongodb/golang-mongodb-fuzzy-query/